# Is it possible to format date rendered by the ui:outputDate Lightning Component?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am currently wanting to output a date returned by my server-side controller to a Lightning component. I know that in VisualForce markup, you have the ability to format dates returned to the VisualForce page as mentioned in this [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm). However, I am not sure how to do this in a Lightning component? It seems you can perform locale formatting at a higher level as show [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_locale_value_provider.htm?search_text=ui:outputdate) in the developer guide, but I am just wanting to format a single date output. The output type is a "Date" primitive type and not DateTime or I might use the `DateTime.format()` method in the server-side controller to do the formatting and do something like `DateTime.format('MMM, d')` which is the format that I need (i.e. Jul 05).

Has anyone had any experience doing this in the Lightning component? I have had some issues getting it to work correctly in the server-side controller. The date that is sent back from the server-side controller is a day behind the actual record date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ui:outputDate` component has an attribute called `langLocale` which you can pass a country code to and an attribute called `format` that should follow the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` interface. Thus, you should be able to do

```
<ui:outputDate format="MMM d" value={!v.date}/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anywhere in the Lightning Component Developer guide that shows those attributes? I wanted to make sure I didn't miss it.

Comment: @DanielFuller - they're not in the dev guide, but they are in the reference, which you can find at https://YOUR-INSTANCE.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app. This will list the various attributes supported for each component. However, this documentation sometimes references components that aren't public, so I pair it with the full aura reference: http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference. This contains every component in aura, many of which aren't in Lightning yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have just created a custom date picker which will enable you to modify/tinker with the locale settings as you will have full control. [Here](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2016/08/build-lightning-date-picker) is the blog post link.

This date picker is styled using the proper SLDS css, so will fit right into your SLDS Page or Lightning App.

I tried to eliminate any dependencies and would have fully succeeded except for a bug with the Locker Service (it seems to prevent some values being returned from string to date methods called on the `localizationService` object. Hence, it does require moment.js at present.

In the meantime, here is all the code on github: [Datepicker](https://github.com/rapsacnz/DatePicker)

Of course, a gif too:

[image: Datepicker gif]

Let me know if you find any bugs.